# Team Foundation Server Changes Lost - Still shows files as checked out with pending changes

Tags: visual-studio-2010, version-control, tfs, azure-devops

I have just returned from the weekend to resume working on a VS2010 project using TFS source control. I had about 15 files checked out with changes from the previous week. Upon getting the latest version from source control, all my local changes have somehow been overridden. However, source control still shows all the files as having pending changes. But none of the new code is actually there, and when compared to latest I get a message saying they are identical. Source control shows the files as checked out to me, but when I open the file, I see the little 'locked' icon in file tab header.
Does anyone have experience with TFS losing pending changes, but still reporting these changes in the pending changes window?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?  If you're seeing your name next to an item in Source Control Explorer, but the file is not checked out, then that indicates that it's checked out in a different TFS workspace.  Make sure you're looking at the place on disk you originally checked the items out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could not figure out a solution in time, I've had to begin rework...

Comment: You should look into Shelvesets. A lot of companies have policies where you have to shelve or check in changes on a regular (daily) basis in case your hardware fails or another developer has to take over the work you have done. Not committing changes to the server is like writing a 50 page Word doc and only relying on auto-save :)

Comment: You're absolutely right. Managed to pinpoint the issue to some kind of workspace conflict, as I was still getting some abnormalities when getting latest code and checking in changes (still saw checked out files as being locked). After deleting the workspace and starting anew, everything seems to be back on track. Not sure how it happened in the first place.

Comment: I lost changes to a file I had checked out after get latest. I only noticed because of compile failures. This seriously diminishes my confidence in TFS as a source control system.